# Android Bluetooth auto connect

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bluetooth, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm am looking to make an app that can connect to device automatically and begin sharing data without explicitly being told to by the user (other than the initial bonding). I would like to, if possible:

1. Auto-connect and share data when in range of previously bonded/favorited device
2. Start application on and run methods when connected/signaled by device
3. Maintain connection on sleep.
4. All of this should be run in the background.

I'm mostly wondering how possible all of this is and if there are any relevant tutorials to look at. I've run through a few and am able to connect/read/write to my bluetooth device. I am however binding to an activity which I feel isn't the right thing to do as the bluetooth disconnects on activity change.

The whole idea seems a bit daunting as it takes from a few areas I'm not entirely confident in: Bluetooth/Services/AsynTasks.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: to start bluetooth adapter you can't skip the validation dialog, to pair devices you can't skip the validation dialog =) after that no user action is needed

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that didn't exactly address any of the questions. I have over the last two weeks figured out most of what I need, and will post the solution once I get a chance to remove all of the company sensitive code and clean up my classes. It's a fairly involved solution so it could take a bit to lay out properly.

Comment: Yes i answered to a side requirement of your solution, because in this post there are several questions. On stack overflow you should post one question at a time. Also the whole thing is about giving you a complete solution... You should take a look at the google chat sample which gives you an idea of the connection process. Next is up to you to take from it and make your own solution.

Comment: @HughArchibald did you find a way to auto-connect the devices once bonded ?